# Qnap raid 5 can not be rebuild

Tags: nas

I am pretty new at working with qnap, I am taking care of an old configuration of an ex-employee and I am lost about recent problems coming out with the office NAS.

Everything started with a HDD failure (number 2), the HDD was replace and the NAS restarted. Everything went fine but using the web administrator when I tried to rebuild the RAID 5, the log reported an error in the Disk 1.

I scanned the disk 1 and messages of bad sectors came up.

I replaced disk 1 and started the NAS again, apparently the NAS started fine and I can access the NAS via SSH, HTTP and even the share folder connected to it.
But when I tried to rebuild the RAID 5, I could not do it and the log is reporting:

> [RAID5 Disk Volume: Drive 1 2 3 4 5] Examination Failed.

Also in the logs, when I started the NAS the first entry is:

> Default shareware Web is not found. Apache httpd started failed.

I am pretty lost on what to do now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone with the same problem.

I contacted qnap support.

Unfortunately they discover a failure of read/write in one of my hardrives and it was necessary to be replaced.

After this, they recommend me to remove the RAID and Recreated, after that (around 10 hours) my RAID 5 was working fine and I was able to restore all folders from a backup.